# how to expand my component width in the correct way in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to expand my width in the correct way in react?
[image]
        
            {/*  */}

```
            <AvForm className="needs-validation add-product-form" onValidSubmit={this.onProductFormValidSubmit} onInvalidSubmit={this.onProductFormInvalidSubmit}>   
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-12">

                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">
                                <h5>Create Order</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="card">    
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    {/* <Selector
                                        isMulti={false}
                                        label={"Customer"}
                                        onLoadData={DBProduct.GetAll}
                                        onFilterData={this.filterProductData}
                                        pageSize={1}
                                    /> */}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <AvField type="text" name="note" id="note" label="Note" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>      

                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body">        
                                <Selector
                                    isMulti={false}
                                    label={"Product"}
                                    onLoadData={DBProduct.GetAll}
                                    onInputChange={this.onProductInputChange}
                                    onFilterData={this.filterProductData}
                                    pageSize={pageSize}
                                />
                            </div> 
                        </div> 

                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body">        
                                <Selector
                                    isMulti={false}
                                    label={"Discount"}
                                    onLoadData={DBDiscount.GetAll}
                                    onFilterData={this.filterDiscountData}
                                    pageSize={1}
                                />
                            </div> 
                        </div> 

                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body">        
                                <Selector
                                    label={"Shipping"}
                                    onLoadData={DBProduct.GetAll}
                                    onFilterData={this.filterProductData}
                                    pageSize={1}
                                />
                            </div> 
                        </div> 

                        <div className="offset-xl-3 offset-sm-4 pull-right">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </AvForm>     

        </div>
    </Fragment>
```

Comment: The "right way" could mean a lot of totally different things depending on the project. Looks like your code uses classnames, can you provide the CSS driving the classes? I suspect the containers automatically grow to fit content so it could be the UI components you render in the "modal" are just narrow.

Comment: Could you provide an online demo? Which may help others to catch up with the problem you are facing quickly. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)